# React - How to use npm-linked module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, npm-link

How can I use a module imported via

```
npm link
```

into webpack for a React application?

```
MyModule_Folder
---------------------------------
    |--package.json
    |--src
        |--myModule
            |--MyComponent.jsx
            |--MyStyle.css
            ...
    |--public
        |--index.html

App
---------------------------------
    |--package.json
    |--src
        ...
```

MyModule/package.json is like this

```
{
    "name": "@mymodule/external",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "src/index.jsx",
    "babel": {
        ...
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        ...
    },
    "scripts": {
        ...
    }
}
```

I typed

```
cd <path_to_MyModule_Folder>
npm link
cd <path_to_MyReactApp>
npm link @mymodule/external
```

If I import my module in this way

```
import { MyModuleClass } from "@mymodule/external";
```

I got an error

Comment: can you please post also your error?

Comment: The error is:  

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of n`



[this is the error url](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]=%20Check%20the%20render%20method%20of%20%60n%60)

Comment: Well then you have wrong MyModule please show full source index.ja of myModule

Comment: In MyModule there is this class `import { Component } from "react";

class Esterno extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('ElementoEsterno.constructor');

    this.val = 15;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Elemento ESTERNO
      </div>
    );
  }


}
export default Esterno
` and an index.js file with this content: `export * from './esterno.jsx';`

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong importing exporting the MyModule

MyModule.js

```
import React from 'react'

export function helloWorld() {}

Class Esterno extends React.Component {
  render() { ..... }
}

export default Esterno
```

index.js

```
export * from './MyModule.js'
```

now imagine it's usage

```
import Esterno from 'mymodule'

console.log(Esterno)
```

you are now importing all contents of module (*) so the otuput will be

```
object = {
 helloWorld: function() {}
 default: class Esterno {}
}
```

now let's change the export in `index.js`

```
export default from './MyModule.js`
```

now the console log will output

```
object = class Esterno {}
```

so you are missing difference between export/import `*` and `default` default is default module and `*` is object of all exports from within module.

Comment: unfortunately I still have the same [error](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]=%20Check%20the%20render%20method%20of%20%60n%60) `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of n`.  [this is app repo](https://github.com/vitolipari/react-import_external_module) and [this is external module repo](https://github.com/vitolipari/react-external_module/)

Comment: Well you have in external module in package.json specified `src/index.js` this file doesn't exists, you have it in root, and you still have export * instead of export default as I wrote ...

Comment: I fixed!!! that are the repos [app](https://github.com/vitolipari/react-import_external_module) and [external module](https://github.com/vitolipari/react-external_module/)

Comment: where? https://github.com/vitolipari/react-external_module/blob/master/index.js#L2 I still see `export *`